# My Java Sentinel-Controlled loop is not working

Tags: java, loops

Trying to write a program that will stop when user input a negative value. However even when user inputted a negative value, loop still continue to run. Has no idea why. Please help!

```
    int input, smallest = 0, largest=0, total = 0, count = 1;
    double avg;

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    input = keyboard.nextInt();

    while(input > 0)
    {

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        largest = keyboard.nextInt();

        count++;

        if (input > largest)
        {
            largest = input;
        }
        else
        {
            smallest = input;
        }    

        total = total + largest + smallest;

    }


    avg = total / count;

    System.out.println("Largest number is: " + largest);
    System.out.println("Smallest number is: " + smallest);
    System.out.printf("Average number is: %.2f \n", avg);
```

Comment: A debugger is an excellent tool for exploring what is going on in situations like this.

Comment: Looks like a typo: assignment to `largest` when the OP meant to assign to `input`.

Comment: Have you check you code once??????

Answer (score 2):

You aren't updating the value of `input` inside your loop.

You need to do something like this:

```
while(input > 0)
{

    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");

    input = keyboard.nextInt(); //Update the input value for this iteration.
    largest = input;
    ...
}
```